# Application gateway multi site set up

Tags: azure, azure-app-services, azure-application-gateway

I have created a set up which uses application gateway to route traffic to app services. Below are the details:

1. Application Gateway - 1
2. Azure App Service - 2
3. App Service Plan - 1
4. VNET and one subnet

App Service - 1 for .net 5 web app, 1 for .net 5 api app

Both browse locally and after publishing to app service, for api app when browsed from Azure portal I have to append /swagger which then translates to https://mywebapiapp.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html

App Gateway Set up
Backend pool
1 for App
Target type: App Services Target: Selected my web app (azure app)

1 for Api Similar with Target azure app service name changed

Backend Setting
[image]

Front end public IP is available

Listeners
[image]

Listener Type is selected as Multi site

Rules

App rule
[image]

Backend targets tab
[image]

Similar set up for API Rule

Hosts file is updated

x.x.x.x [www.fabrikam.com](http://www.fabrikam.com)
x.x.x.x [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)

When I browse fabrikam.com I end up in micorsoft.com/en-in/ not in my azure app hosting the .net 5 web app

First posted on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76763153/application-gateway-multi-site-set-up)

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit